# Updating status and changing its visibility on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to do on Android something like IOS does, which is posting a message and choosing the visibility of that post.

I'm using the follow code to update the user status, although I wanted to give the user a way to choose the visibility of that publication:

```
                GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                     "me/feed", param, HttpMethod.POST,
                     new GraphRequest.Callback() {

                         @Override
                         public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                             Log.d("post page response::", "success " + graphResponse.getRawResponse());

                         }
                     });
                graphRequest.executeAsync();
```

This is the default visibility of the publications on Facebook through the app, to accept the permission:

> publish_actions

Is there a way to call something like this choose box?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this doc - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#pubfields, specifically the fields under the Publish section. 
There is a field called privacy that you can use in order to change the visibility of messages for the user. But note that it's dependent upon the value the user selects when they first grant access to the app. 
It's documented there - Determines the privacy settings of the post. If not supplied, this defaults to the privacy level granted to the app in the Login Dialog. This field cannot be used to set a more open privacy setting than the one granted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I can not replicate the same behaviour as in IOS, I think that field should help.